Jenkins terminates pod while pod still downloads an image
I have an issue with Jenkins where pods (in AWS EKS) are getting terminated by it approximately 6 minutes after creation (and then it tries to create one over and over):
18:42:27  Created Pod: kubernetes <namespace>/<pod1>
18:42:40  Still waiting to schedule task
18:42:40  ‘pod1’ is offline
18:49:28  Created Pod: kubernetes <namespace>/<pod2>
18:56:28  Created Pod: kubernetes <namespace>/<pod3>

Pod is getting terminated before it ends downloading the image (it takes around 12 minutes, image sizes are 2.2 and 10+ GBs):
kubectl describe pod <pod> -n <namespace>
...[cut]...
Status:                    Terminating (lasts <invalid>)
...[cut]...
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  Scheduled          12m   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned <namespace>/<pod> to <node>
  Normal  ResourceAllocated  12m   vpc-resource-controller  Allocated Resource vpc.amazonaws.com/PrivateIPv4Address: 172.24.127.199/23 to the pod
  Normal  Pulled             12m   kubelet                  Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:windowsservercore-ltsc2019" already present on machine
  Normal  Created            12m   kubelet                  Created container jnlp
  Normal  Started            11m   kubelet                  Started container jnlp
  Normal  Pulling            11m   kubelet                  Pulling image "<image>"
  Normal  Pulled             1s    kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "<image>" in 11m45.3549401s (11m45.3549401s including waiting)
  Normal  Created            1s    kubelet                  Created container main

Had anyone encountered similar issue? What could it be and how to fix it?

Can you please share more details about the cluster, pod, etc. ? Specifically container resources, requests, limits, etc.
